# Unity does not load script when running play in the editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a Movable script attached to a gameObject like this. When I press the play button, Unity does not load the script even though it was running normally before. How to fix this error?

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

Comment: Do you have compile errors? You need to fix those.